# Converting text data file to csv format via shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm looking for a straightforward console solution to change a text file which looks like this:

```
...
Gender: M
Age: 46
History: 01305
Gender: F
Age: 46
History: 01306
Gender: M
Age: 19
History: 01307
Gender: M
Age: 19
History: 01308
....
```

To csv file like this one:

```
Gender,Age,History
M,46,01305
F,46,01306
M,19,01307
M,19,01308
```

Any help appreciated

---

With following solutions I've received this output. Am I doing something wrong?

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "Gender,Age,History%s",ORS;FS=":"}{c++} {sub(/^   */,"",$2);printf "%s%s",$2,(c==3)?ORS:","}c==3{c=0}' data.txt >> 1.csv

Gender,Age,History
M
,37
,00001
M
,37
,00001
M
,41
,00001
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Also you'll find a lot of duplicate questions with exact requirement `:-)`

Comment: This might help anyways `awk 'BEGIN{printf "Gender,Age,History%s",ORS} {FS=":";count++} {sub(/^ */,"",$2);printf "%s%s",$2,(cou
nt==3)?ORS:","}count==3{count=0}' file `

Comment: Note an inadvertent space in `count` above. The space should be removed. It is even better to put the field separator in the `BEGIN` block as in `awk 'BEGIN{printf "Gender,Age,History%s",ORS;FS=":"}{c++} {sub(/^ */,"",$2);printf "%s%s",$2,(c==3)?ORS:","}c==3{c=0}' file`

Comment: @sjsam can you take a look again? I tried your solution, it works, but there some issues. I'm using OSX shell, if it's necessary. Thanks a lot tho

Comment: I am puzzled with what you got, especially with the newlines before the commas. I am not sure it has got anything to do with you using the OSX..lemme have a research

Comment: I am puzzled with what you got, especially with the newlines before the commas. I am not sure it has got anything to do with you using the OSX. Anyways it is worth reading [this](http://obswww.unige.ch/~segransa/HELP/replace.html) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/439443/412318). Hope it helps `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should help:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":|\n";RS="Gender";OFS=",";print "Gender,Age,History"}$0{print $2,$4,$6}' file
```

With your example as input, it gives:

```
Gender,Age,History
 M, 46, 01305
 F, 46, 01306
 M, 19, 01307
 M, 19, 01308
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in bash. Assuming your datafile is called data.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Gender,Age,History"
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s' "$(cut -d ' ' -f2 <<< $line )"
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^History.* ]]; then
    printf "\n"
  else
    printf ","
  fi
done < data.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Gender,Age,History
M,46,01305
F,46,01306
M,19,01307
M,19,01308
```

Comment: You should double quote `$(cut -d ' ' -f2 <<< $line )`. Also, `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes.`Here strings: <<< WORD` appeared in `bash 2.05b-alpha1`. Though we can be pretty sure the op will have a later version of `bash`.

Comment: Updated with @sjsam comments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtin commands only, I would say:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Gender,Age,History"
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^Gender:\ *([^\ ]+) ]]; then
        r=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $line =~ ^Age:\ *([^\ ]+) ]]; then
        r+=,${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $line =~ ^History:\ *([^\ ]+) ]]; then
        echo $r,${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi
done < data.text
```

Comment: `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes. Also double quote `$r` & `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know where exactly was the problem
So I decided to cleanup the data from all of characters except ones, which are supposed to be there (most probably unusual end of the line symbol)

```
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z*0-9:]/ /g;s/  */ /g' history.txt > output.txt
```

And after that succesfully used the solution from @sjsam

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "Gender,Age,History%s",ORS;FS=":"}{c++} {sub(/^   */,"",$2);printf "%s%s",$2,(c==3)?ORS:","}c==3{c=0}' data.txt >> 1.csv
```

Thanks everyone!